# How can rails app accept non-alphanumeric character in url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, encoding, utf-8, webrick

I am trying to construct search method by accepting some keywords as a GET request.

For exmaple, 'articles/search/computer' will likely search for articles that have keyword computer.

Now, if search term contains some other languages, such as Korean word, the rails app produces the following page.

```
Internal Server Error


"\x80" on CP949

WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-02-18) at hanun.com:3000
```

and the server has log as follows

```
[2011-05-15 19:58:05] ERROR Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError: "\x80" on CP949
```

I am in a window 7, with ruby 1.9.2p180, rails 3.0.5. I am using webrick as a development server. 
How can I resolve this problem so that the rails app will accept non-alphanumeric characters as url string??

This url does works: http://127.0.0.1/articles?search=한국

However, following url does not work: http://127.0.0.1/articles/search/한국

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was not from rails, but from OS. In windows, any non-alphabetic characters won't be accepted in url if it came in as a shorthand url in rails app. In linux, it works fine. This only happens to rails.

Note that this problems only occurs in Webrick && windows 7 && rails environment.

Answer (score 0):

URLS sent through http can only be basic ascii, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp or http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html

Essentially, your url becomes:  http://127.0.0.1/articles/search/%26%2354620%3B%26%2344397%3B

Comment: Yes, I have developed some apps in PHP that accept such non-ascii strings. And for this case, if non-ascii chracters are passed in as variable values, it works fine. However, it does not work if non-ascii characters are in shortened url.